# How do I get a shortname for a folder in WiX for a Windows Installer property?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

I am trying to register an out-of-process COM file (.exe) through WiX after extracting the COM registration from regspy.exe, and am running into the problem that the registry key I need to write is:

```
<RegistryValue Value="C:\PROGRA~1\COMMON~1\file.exe /Automation" Type="String" />
```

Now I would like to use the Windows Installer property [CommonFilesFolder] as not everyone installs to C:\

For an in-process (.dll) the long name is acceptable:

```
<RegistryValue Value="[CommonFilesFolder]file.dll" Type="string" />
```

But it appears this in not true for out-of-process.  Is there a way to convince or convert [CommonFilesFolder] to the short name?  This is a particular problem for x64, as the name will resolve to C:\PROGRA~2\ instead of C:\PROGRA~1\

Comment: Putting quotes around the executable name should also work with long paths, like `Value="&quot;[CommonFilesFolder]file.exe&quot; /Automation"`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [!idOfFile] to get the full short path. (See [Formatted in MSI SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368609%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the full list of special formatting keys.)